Empty variable in GitHub Actions YAML via secrets
For some reason S3_BUCKET is empty/undefined:
env:
  AWS_REGION: us-west-2
  S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets[env.ENVIRONMENT == 'production' && 'cms-prod' || 'cms-dev'] }}
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets[env.ENVIRONMENT == 'production' && 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID' || 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] }}
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets[env.ENVIRONMENT == 'production' && 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY' || 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] }}

How could that be?

Try with
S3_BUCKET: ${{ env.ENVIRONMENT == 'production' && secrets.cms-prod || secrets.cms-dev }}

The issue with the S3_BUCKET being empty or undefined is likely due to incorrect syntax in your GitHub Actions configuration. You need to use a ternary operator to handle conditional assignments within your YAML file properly.
I’ll suggest you replace your S3_BUCKET line with:
S3_BUCKET: ${{ env.ENVIRONMENT == 'production' ? secrets.CMS_PROD : secrets.CMS_DEV }}

This syntax checks if ENVIRONMENT is 'production'. If true, it uses the secret CMS_PROD; otherwise, it uses CMS_DEV.
Ensure that your secret names CMS_PROD and CMS_DEV are correctly defined in the GitHub repository's secrets settings and match the case exactly as they appear.

I upvoted this prematurely - I don't think ternary operator is supported (sadly)

It's actually possible, but the syntax is different: ${{ x && 'ifTrue' || 'ifFalse'  }} reference
